# I want to split BizTalk response message

Tags: xml, schema, biztalk

i am getting a response in this format.
i want to split the message in to different messages

```
<ROOT>
<id/>
<date>
<fieldname/>
<fieldvalue/>
<fieldname/>
<fieldvalue/>
<fieldname/>
<fieldvalue/>
<id/>
<date>
<fieldname/>
<fieldvalue/>
<fieldname/>
<fieldvalue/>
<fieldname/>
<fieldvalue/>
</ROOT>
```

where fieldname and fieldvalue can be many

i want to split this 
starting from id to next id is a new record

Comment: Can you first describe what you have already tried?  This is a fairly routine operation.

Comment: Your XML isn't even valid.  Your date elements aren't self terminating nor have a closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend first mapping towards an own, custom schema.

Something like this:

```
<ROOT>
  <Message>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>2017-09-18</date>
    <fieldname>fieldvalue</fieldname>
    <fieldname2>fieldvalue2</fieldname2>
    <fieldname3>fieldvalue3</fieldname3>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>2017-09-18</date>
    <fieldname>fieldvalue</fieldname>
    <fieldname2>fieldvalue2</fieldname2>
    <fieldname3>fieldvalue3</fieldname3>
  </Message>
</ROOT>
```

Once you have this, you can use XML debatching to de-batch your messages based on the `/Root` Body path.